# Скомпилировал exe файл но ничего не происходит при его запуске

Tags: python, dll

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Window 7,Python 3.7 В пайчарме код отлично работает.Компилирую в exe запускаю ничего не происходит.Запустил через cmd пишет error loading python dll python37.dll
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит не видит библиотеку python37.dll. Чтобы видел, она должна быть рядом с exe файлом.

Comment: До пай чарма стоял Тони.Там не было таких проблем при компилации

Comment: сделал как вы написали поймал другую ошибку No module named 'encodings'

Comment: Я без понятия, кто такой Тони. Pycharm/Тони вообще не имеют отношения к "компиляции". Скорее всего для сборки в exe вы используете pyinstaller, и видимо в этот раз собирали без опции onefile, и вытащили exe отдельно от остальных файлов.

Comment: когда я пытаюсь запустить exe файл из папки Билд происходит то же самое

Comment: вот.запускаю екзешник вообще ничего не происходит.а в пайчарме все отлично

Comment: Соберите с ключом --onefile и не мучайтесь.

Comment: хотелось бы и так и так уметь